# Combos dependientes con jQuery, Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

he encontrado un ejercicio en Internet el cual no se porqué me arroja estos errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#marca").on('change', function () {
                $("#marca option:selected").each(function () {
                    elegido=$(this).val();
                    $.post("", { elegido: elegido }, function(data){
                        $("#modelo").html(data);
                    });         
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

<

    /head>

    <body>
        <form class="row" action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label for="marca">Marca</label>
                <select name="marca" id="marca" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">Renault</option>
                    <option value="2">Seat</option>
                    <option value="3">Peugeot</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label for="modelo">Modelo</label>
                <select name="modelo" id="modelo" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">4</option>
                    <option value="2">5</option>
                    <option value="3">7</option>
                    <option value="4">21</option>
                    <option value="5">Scennic</option>
                    <option value="6">Traffic</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>


    <?php
    $html = "";
    if ($_POST["elegido"]==1) {
        $html = '
        <option value="1">4</option>
        <option value="2">5</option>
        <option value="3">7</option>
        <option value="4">21</option>
        <option value="5">Scennic</option>
        <option value="6">Traffic</option>
        ';  
    }

    if ($_POST["elegido"]==2) {
        $html = '
        <option value="1">Ibiza</option>
        <option value="2">Toledo</option>
        <option value="3">Cordoba</option>
        <option value="4">Arosa</option>
        ';  
    }

    if ($_POST["elegido"]==3) {
        $html = '
        <option value="1">106</option>
        <option value="2">206</option>
        <option value="3">306</option>
        ';  
    }
    echo $html; 
    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Las lineas en donde me marca el Undefined index:
son estas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden explicar Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente, estas tratando de comprobar si el contenido de $_POST['elegido'] es igual a X cosa pero esto no debería ser así ya que cuando no se ha entrado por el método post la variable $_POST no existe. Hazlo así para evitar el error:

La función  **isset** comprueba si la variable existe: (https://www.php.net/isset)

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST))
{
    $html = "";
    if ($_POST["elegido"]==1) {
        $html = '
        <option value="1">4</option>
        <option value="2">5</option>
        <option value="3">7</option>
        <option value="4">21</option>
        <option value="5">Scennic</option>
        <option value="6">Traffic</option>
        ';  
    }

    if ($_POST["elegido"]==2) {
        $html = '
        <option value="1">Ibiza</option>
        <option value="2">Toledo</option>
        <option value="3">Cordoba</option>
        <option value="4">Arosa</option>
        ';  
    }

    if ($_POST["elegido"]==3) {
        $html = '
        <option value="1">106</option>
        <option value="2">206</option>
        <option value="3">306</option>
        ';  
    }
    echo $html; 

}
?>
```

Como alternativa también puedes desactivar todos los errores: `error_reporting(0); // al comienzo de tu archivo php`